# How do I make a div animation in css3 happen using hover on another div?

Tags: css, html, hover, transform

So I have this css3 animation set up that is supposed to scale the div with the class "label" from 0px,47px to 170px,47px when you hover the mouse over the div "house"
Except that it doesn't work, and i have no idea why.

```
<style type="text/css">
@keyframes labels {
    0% {width:0px; height:47px}
    100% {width: 170px; height:47px}
}
.hover{
}
.hover:hover{
    background-size: contain;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    cursor:pointer;
}
#house{
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    padding: 2em;
    background-color: #069;
    border: thick solid #FC0;
    color: #09C;
    text-decoration: underline overline;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4em;
    left: 4em;
}
.label{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 47px;
    background-image: url(tests-02.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    top: 5em;
    left: 47px;
    background-size: 100%;
}
#house:hover .label{
    animation:labels;
    -webkit-animation:labels;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="house" class="hover">TEST</div>
<div class="label"></div>
</body>
```

The picture won't load because it's local so I filled "label" with a black background instead in the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/YFRHR/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question title is misleading.
You 2 problems:

1) animation syntax, there are missing properties

```
.hover:hover + .label{
animation: labels 1s infinite;
-webkit-animation: wlabels 1s infinite;
}
```

2) missing webkit support:

```
@-webkit-keyframes wlabels {
    0% {width:0px; height:47px}
    100% {width: 170px; height:47px}
}
@-keyframes labels {
    0% {width:0px; height:47px}
    100% {width: 170px; height:47px}
}
```

But the hover per se is working.

[update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/YFRHR/2/)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I didn't know about those missing properties. This works great but how would I get it to only loop one time per hover?

Comment: Alright, so I replaced infinite with 1 but after it plays once it goes back to its original 0px wide mode. How would I get it to stay 170px until the hovering ends?

Comment: You didn't allow me time to answer !